# Post on multiple friend Facebook wall in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to post a message on all of my friends wall

Following is the code that ih ave found

```
 [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"friend_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

The big problem is how can i get `friend_id`? is it their emails? Or how to get all lists of my friends ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

will request the list of your friends, provided that you are correctly authenticated.

Then implement your delegate method in order to extract the id you need.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    items = result[@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary * friend in items) {
        long long friendId = [friend[@"id"] longLongValue];
        // Do something with the Id
    }
}
```

Comment: what is _Facebook in this casE?